# azue synapse copy from Azure Sql to Datalake Table

Tags: azure-synapse

i want to copy data from azure Sql Tabel to Datalake Storage account table using synapse analytics, in the Datalake table i want to store table name and max id for the incremental load, is this possibe

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is only to transfer the data from Azure SQL Database to Data Lake Storage (ADLS) account and no big data analysis required, you can simply use `Copy activity` in either Azure Data Factory (ADF) or Synapse pipeline.

ADF also allows you to perform required **transformation** on your data before storing it into the destination using `data flow activity`.

Refer this official tutorial to [Copy data from a SQL Server database to Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-portal).

Now coming to Incremental load, ADF and Synapse pipelines both provide complete inbuilt support for it. You need to select a column as `Watermark column` in your source table.

> Watermark column in the source data store, which can be used to slice
> the new or updated records for every run. Normally, the data in this
> selected column (for example, last_modify_time or ID) keeps increasing
> when rows are created or updated. The maximum value in this column is
> used as a watermark.

Microsoft provides a complete step-by-step tutorial to [Incrementally load data from Azure SQL Database to Azure Blob storage using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-portal) which you can follow and implement with appropriate changes as per your use case.

Apart from watermark technique, there are other methods which you can choose to manage incremental load. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview).

Comment: The requirement is indeed to transfer the data from Azure SQL Database to Data Lake Storage (ADLS) Table and not a File.

Comment: So you can definitely go for `copy activity` in ADF. Follow the shared tutorial link. Step-by-step given to achieve the task.